# Showing that a $X(u,v)$ is one-to-one

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

I am currently reviewing for a differential geometry exam, and seem to be having trouble with the algebra required to show that the parameterization

$$X(u,v)=(u+v, u+v, uv)$$

is one-to-one.

I know in order to show its one-to-one, I have to prove the following:

for $X(u_1,v_1)=X(u_2,v_2)$, that $u_1=u_2$ and that $v_1=v_2.$

I am currently going in circles in my algebra (I've shown that $u_1=v_1$ and that $u_2=v_2$), so if someone could show me the correct algebra, that would be brilliant!

Thanks

Comment: Is that the right map? As of now, it looks like $X(0,1)=X(1,0)$, for example.

Answer (score 0):

*Probable Hint*: Let be $U\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ open set and $f:U\to \mathbb{R}^n$ a differentiable application of class $C^1$. If, for $a\in U$, $f'(a): \mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is one-to-one then $f$ is locally one-to-one.